# My Schengen visa expired on 28 June but the police has given me an extension till the 9 july

Tags: visas, schengen, legal, indian-citizens, visa-extensions

Will I have a problem in getting a Schengen visa again? Does getting an extension of a week after expiration of the visa stain my intentions or will they refuse me the visa next time? I am an Indian citizen.

Comment: Plz do help me out. Im really worried

Comment: If the you get the extension officially, then there should be nothing to worry about..

Comment: keep the documentation of this extension (if it's not in the passport)

Comment: Why have the police extended it? That might tell us more about if ti will be a problem.

Comment: @Swapnil, critically important here:  did you pay anything for the extension?

Comment: No i did not pay anything for extension

Comment: @Swapnil, in that case, it's best to double check with a lawyer

Answer (score 1):

I can't predict exactly how a consulate will look at it but getting an extension is certainly not a valid ground for refusal. As they are quite hard to get and imply that you had a very good reason for not leaving and were proactive about informing the authorities, I would not worry.

Comment: Thanx  i feel a little relieved

Comment: Are you sure it was the police who extended the visa?

Comment: Yeah they were policemen for sure

Comment: @GayotFow I guess you want to address your question to the OP? It's true that in many countries, the police is not in charge of this but it is in some (I think Ireland is one such state, even if it's obviously not Schengen). I don't even know which country the OP was in.

Comment: @Relaxed, Ireland isn't in Schengen, no matter.  You ARE, however, very well versed on EU regulations with respect to competence requirements.